# Android Fragment OnTouchEvent on button from other Layout

Tags: android, xml, android-fragments, android-camera2

I'm trying to make `Google's API Camera2Video` work with `onTouch`. `Camera2Video` inflates layout called `fragment_camera2_video`, but I need to get the fragment to listen to another layout's button clicks.

I have added `onTouchListener` to `Camera2Video`. Then once it has `inflated` the one `view` to show the camera preview, I want to access button from another `layout`

Here is the `Camera2VideoFragment` from which I am trying to access the button from. The button I am supposed to get is located inside layout called `song_player.xml`. 
Since the `Camera2VideoFragment` is too long to post here I will add a link : https://pastebin.com/iuCEd1Sx

The official `Google's API Camera2Video` can be seen here: https://github.com/googlesamples/android-Camera2Video/tree/master/Application/src/main

Alternatively It would be fine if I could start the `Camera2Video` from another activity, using its `startRecordingVideo()` and `stopRecordingVideo()`. I tried doing it by creating methods inside the `Camera2VideFragment` creating new instance of it and using the methods, but calling the `stopRecordingVideo()` would give an error, saying that `MediaPlayer is null`.

I am aware that posting `links` is bad practise, but the codes for these are too long!

Answer (score 0):

Create an interface. Implement it in the fragment.call that interface in button click so that method implementation in fragment will be called.

Comment: Well its basically the same as implementing OnTouchListener, but the problem is that I can't get the correct view to get the button.

Answer (score 0):

Try create a LocalBroadcastReceiver. Register the receiver on the class that you wants receive the command. And, through IntentFilter you can call a method inside another place.